# get the selected value of the select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the selectbox and that selected box has one value selected, now i can change the value and i want that it should pick the changed value instead of the already selected value

i am using it like this

```
var x= document.getElementById("numbervalue");
        var y= document.getElementById("dayvalue");
        ax = dnum.options[x.selectedIndex].value;
        at = dDay.options[y.selectedIndex].value;
```

ut the above only giving me the previously selected value instead of new one

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mcve] so we can see how you use this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this helps

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>get value of select box</title>
<style>
body {
  font-family: Courier, monospace;
 }
#output {
 margin-top:10px;
 text-align:center;
 padding:10px;
 width: 200px;
 height:100px;
 border-style:groove;
}
.info {
 font-size: 12px; 
 width: 270px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h3>select box stack overflow</h3>
<p class = "info">On any change in an option element, the JS will use the vals from the numbervalue option element to reset the val in the dayvalue option element.<br><br>You must change the number to change anything</p>
<label for = "dayvalue">Choose a day:</label>
<select name="dayvalue" id="dayVal" onchange="readBoxes()">
 <option value="m">Monday</option>
 <option value="t">Tuesday</option>
 <option value="w">Wednesday</option>
 <option value="th">Thursday</option>
 <option value="f">Friday</option>
 <option value="sat">Saturday</option>
 <option value="sun">Sunday</option>
</select>
<br>
<label for = "numbervalue">Choose a number:</label>
<select name="numbervalue" id="numVal" onchange="readBoxes()">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
 <option value="4">4</option>
 <option value="5">5</option>
 <option value="6">6</option>
 <option value="7">7</option>
</select>
 
<div id="output">Day of Week</div>

<p>-h34dsp1nns</p>

<script>
function readBoxes() {
 var out = document.getElementById("output");
 var day = document.getElementById("dayVal");
 var num = document.getElementById("numVal");
 
 var numIndex = num.selectedIndex;
 
 day.selectedIndex = numIndex; //resets the index
 
 var dayVal = day[numIndex]; //gets the option element at an index
 
 out.innerHTML = dayVal.text;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: problem is i do not have a onchange event on my select boxes, all i have is an click button on my form and from there i have to check if the value is new one selected from dropdown

Comment: That shouldn't matter. The function readBoxes() in this code example is triggered by the onChange() event of the select boxes, but it could just as easily be triggered by a button press event. Can you describe your use case in more detail or, even better, post the code you have so far?